# A BDD (RSpec-like) testing library for Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

Now that we have lambda expression it should be possible to have a Java unit testing library that offers a syntax similar to that of (say) RSpec. I imagine something like:

```
  describe("some behavior", () -> {
    beforeEach(() -> {
      // do some initialization...
    });
    describe("sub behavior 1", () -> {
      // some assertions ...
    });
    describe("sub behavior 2", () -> {
      // some assertions ....
    });
  });
```

Is there any library like that out there?

Comment: Cucumber is BDD, but is a pretty different animal than RSpec.

Comment: ? https://code.google.com/p/spock/  ?

Comment: The question would not be closed if the OP had included some idea how to *implement* such a lib. But then it would still be off-topic here in SO and on-topic in programmers.SE. But Asking "is there any library like that out there?" is guaranteed to get your question closed.

Comment: Ginkgo4j - a Java-port of RSpec using lambda's

Answer (score 7):

Afaik, [**Oleaster**](https://github.com/mscharhag/oleaster) is a lib that does that.

> Oleaster allows you to write JUnit tests like you would write Jasmine
>   tests.
>
> An Oleaster JUnit test looks like this:
>
> ```
> @RunWith(OleasterRunner.class)
> public class OleasterIntroductionTest {{
>     describe("A suite", () -> {
>         it("contains a spec with an expectation", () -> {
>             expect(40 + 2).toEqual(42);
>         });
>     });
> }}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Please consider [spock](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/), it was inspired from rspec and others.

It Just reached 1.0.

From the page...

> In Behavior Driven Development, customer-facing features (called
>   stories) are described in a given-when-then format. Spock directly
>   supports this style of specification with the given: label:

```
> given: "an empty bank account" // ...
> 
> when: "the account is credited $10" // ...
> 
> then: "the account's balance is $10" // ... As noted
```

Comment: It's perhaps interesting that `spock` uses groovy

Comment: Using groovy is exactly why we didn't like it. :)